# What is this plant with no leaves and a thick red stalk?

Tags: identification

We live in a lodgepole pine forest and this plant is popping up everywhere. Is this a fungus of some kind?

[image]

Comment: Eastern Oregon Pine forest, in the Cascades rain shadow area. I drove through similar on the way to Fort Rock (weathered volcano tuff ring) before we broke out into the plains land.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like [Pterospora Andromeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterospora). From wikipedia:

> Pterospora, commonly known as pinedrops, Albany beechdrops, or giant
>   bird's nest is a monotypic genus in the subfamily Monotropoidiae of
>   the blueberry family, the Ericaceae, and includes only the species
>   Pterospora andromedea.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterospora) It grows in coniferous or mixed forests. It
>   is native to North America from southern Canada to the mountains of
>   Mexico and is most commonly found in the western half of the
>   continent, though small isolated populations are found in the
>   northeastern United States and eastern Canada. Along with Monotropa it
>   is one of the more frequently encountered members of the
>   Monotropoidiae.

Photo that looks very much like yours:

[image]

Comment: Similar to Ground Cone. Boschniakia, a homoparasitic plant that absorbs nutrients from tree and brush roots.

Comment: I was also looking at Corallorhiza in an old book.  Yours is correct, it has to be.  Thank you!!